# Django give Error 500 for all static files like CSS and Images, when DEBUG is False

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-settings, django-debug-toolbar, django-errors

I've tried different solutions already posted by users, but they didn't work for me.

**settings.py** of Project

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[

    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

All my CSS files are in style folder inside the static folder.
And all images are in the media folder.

**Browser Consol Logs**

```
        Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/styles/LandingPage_CSS.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
        icons8-user-48.png:1 
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
        Doorakart%20icon.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
        apple.jpg:1 
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
        banana.jpg:1 
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
        watermelon.jpg:1 
    .
    .
    .

    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
    Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/styles/LandingPage_CSS.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

**Example of HTML file**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles/LandingPage_CSS.css' %}">
</head>

   ...
      # IMAGES ARE LOADED LIKE THIS
     <img src="media/{{item.itemImage}}" alt="img" class=" card-img-top">

   ...
```

Also, I want to disable `DEBUG` because I want to make my custom 404 Error page.
404 page will also contain static Image and CSS, is it possible? Please help me with that too.

Comment: This is expected behavior. Django does *not* serve static files or media files in production. You should configure nginx, etc. to serve files.

Answer (score 4):

This is **expected behavior**. Django does ***not* serve static files** or media files in production. You should configure nginx, etc. to serve files.

As is specified in the [*Static file development view* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static-file-development-view):

> This view will only work if `DEBUG` is `True`.
>
> That’s because this **view is grossly inefficient and probably
>   insecure**. This is only intended for local development, and **should
>   never be used in production**.

Normally you should configure `nginx`, `apache` web server to serve static files. These web servers are likely more efficient, and have more dedicated tooling for security.

Django offers some tooling to help you set up static files, for example with the [**`collectstatic`** command [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic) to collect static files in a single location. The documentation furthermore describes how to make a [basic configuration for *apache* and *nginx*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files).

There is also a package [**`whitenoise`**](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) if you really want to let Django serve static files in production, but as [said in the documentation](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/#isn-t-serving-static-files-from-python-horribly-inefficient):

> **Isn’t serving static files from Python horribly inefficient?**
>
> The short answer to this is that if you care about performance and
>   efficiency then you should be **using WhiteNoise behind a CDN** like
>   CloudFront. If you’re doing that then, because of the caching headers
>   WhiteNoise sends, the vast majority of static requests will be served
>   directly by the CDN without touching your application, so it really
>   doesn’t make much difference how efficient WhiteNoise is.
>
> That said, WhiteNoise is pretty efficient. Because it only has to
>   serve a fixed set of files it does all the work of finding files and
>   determining the correct headers upfront on initialization. Requests
>   can then be served with little more than a dictionary lookup to find
>   the appropriate response. Also, when used with gunicorn (and most
>   other WSGI servers) the actual business of pushing the file down the
>   network interface is handled by the kernel’s very efficient `sendfile`
>   syscall, not by Python.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and you should update your nginx or any another serve configuration. Just add your media and static path like below.

```
 location /media/ {
        root /path/to/your/project;
    }
location /static/ {
        root /path/to/your/project;
    }
```

Project path means where your media and static directories are located. Wish this helps you.