# Need solution to display media files in template when debug == false

Tags: python, django

My Django project is displaying media in templates if debug == True no problem at all but the problem arises when I set debug to False
Django fails to load them if debug == False( There are some solutions out there but I am not able to wrap my head around them as
I am new to Django ). Can someone please tell me what is the best and easiest way to solve this issue?
Note: I want to host my website on my local wifi (not on pythonanywhere or any other web hosting service)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It does not fail to load them. Django does not serve media files on production.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61611017/67579

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me below method worked:
In urls.py I added this line:
`from django.views.static import serve`
add those two urls in urlpatterns:

```
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), 
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
```

and both static and media files were accesible when DEBUG=FALSE.
Hope it helps
For more info. , Take a look at [Why does DEBUG=False setting make my django Static Files Access fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836674/why-does-debug-false-setting-make-my-django-static-files-access-fail)

Comment: . It worked :-) The media files are being displayed now. I have been searching for a solution and you solved it. Once again thank you :-)