# Static and media files are not loaded in production

Tags: python, django, web, static, media

You can see my urls.py and my settings.py.

**Server**

NGINX, gunicorn

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("appCms.urls"))
] 

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn/')

MEDIA_URL ='/mediafiles/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mediafiles_cdn/')
```

Comment: Django does not serve static/media files in production. That should be handled by Nginx/Apache/...: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61611017/67579

Comment: The reason is that it is considered inefficient and likely unsafe. As in, one could likely try to use Django's system to serve static files to obtain files that a user should not have access to.

Comment: Can you open F12 in chrome? In the tab console, appear if there is an error. Show don't find the file "./static/..."? Are you config the path in IIS?