# Django 3.1.1 Static files Not Found

Tags: python, django, heroku

Currently having an issue where my static resources aren't loading after I host on Heroku. This is the error I'm getting:
[DevTools Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guXq4.png)

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('doppelganger.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

My settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "doppelganger/static"),
]
```

Directory structure:

```
project
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
doppelganger
    static
       js
       img
       css
```

Django version: 3.1.1
Python version: 3.8.6

I have tried running `python manage.py collectstatic` and I'm still seeing the same errors.

Any other suggestion I can try to help fix `"GET /static/css/beta_main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 Not found` ?

Comment: Django does not serve static files on production.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61610680/67579