# 404 Error when saving imagefield in admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, python-3.7

I have my project on production, I get an error trying to upload image in admin panel. I have uploaded all my settings static and others needed.

Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    https://reliancestandardtrust.com/admin/myapp/profile/add/
Raised by:  django.contrib.admin.options.add_view
The current path, myapp/profile/add/, didn't match any of these.

settings static:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/relipoqe/public_html/media'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/relipoqe/public_html/static'
```

Root url:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('', include('myapp.urls', namespace='site')),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                      document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                      document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Myapp url:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url

from myapp.views import (
    IndexView,
    ProfileView,
)
app_name = 'myapp'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', IndexView, name='index'),
    path('secure/ibank/p/', ProfileView, name='profile'),
]
```

Model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True) 
    profile_pic = models.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Profile'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Profiles'
        ordering = ['-date']

    '''Method to filter database results'''
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Admin:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Profile

class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'user', 
        'date', 
    )
    search_fields = (
        'user__username',       
    )
admin.site.register(Profile, ProfileAdmin)
```

Comment: Django does *not* serve static/media files on production.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61611017/67579

Comment: @Willem... Honestly this issue worked on my other project on production, but i do not know when this particular project throws this error. Is there a way i can solve this?

Comment: well this looks more like an issue with an `<a href="">` that is relative, did you define the URLs yourself instead of `{% url ... %}`.

Comment: did you set `DEBUG = False` on production? Bas3ed on the error message you did not, which is a rather (serious) security issue as well.

Comment: @Willem.. Yes i defined the URLs myself. this error only occur when i try to upload an image in django admin. If i remove the imagefield in model, it works correctly. But it is important i upload an image to a profile

Comment: well then likely you wrote a *relative* URL in the `<form action="...">`.

Comment: @Willem... I am not uploading image using a form, i am uploading image from the admin panel. This works well in development, but i am having issues in production